# Debouncing events and stale closures in functional React

Tags: react.js, event-handling, jsx, closure

**Context**

As part of our React application, in which we use functional components, we encountered a scenario where we needed to debounce parts of a DOM event listener for usability purposes. The actual scenario is a bit complex but I'll be simplifying it in the next sections for the sake of the question.

The partial debounce created issues with the fact that we use functional components, and I have found an approach that deals with them. However, I am here to question the elegance of my solution.

**Scenario and Issues**

Let's imagine we have a simple React functional component with a counter in the state and a button that increments it. The click event also logs the new value (in the real scenario, this second action is an HTTP call), but we don't want to "log" on every increment, hence the need to debounce the event. This way, only when the user is done mashing the button do we execute this secondary action.

```js
// debounce implementation
const debounce = (listenerFn, delay) => {
    let timeout = null;
    return (...eventArguments) => {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(() => { listenerFn(...eventArguments); }, delay);
    }
}

const App = () => {
    const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(0);
    
    // logger and its debounced version
    const logger = () => { console.log(counter); }
    const debouncedLogger = debounce(logger, 1000);
    
    // click event handler
    const onClick = () => {
        setCounter(counter + 1);
        debouncedLogger();
    }
        
    return (
        <button onClick={ onClick }>{ counter }</button>
    );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

This clearly does not do the trick. React executes the `App()` function on each render cycle, this effectively creates a newly debounced version of `logger()` every time. When you execute this code, you'll see after starting to mash the button and a second passes, `logger()` is executed on each increment.

To stop this from happening, let's make sure to only create the debounced event listener once, the first time. A quick and dirty way to do so is to declare `debouncedLogger` at the module level and only assign its value once.

```js
const debounce = (listenerFn, delay) => {
    let timeout = null;
    return (...eventArguments) => {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(() => { listenerFn(...eventArguments); }, delay);
    }
}
let debouncedLogger = null;
const App = () => {
    const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(0);
    
    const logger = () => { console.log(counter); }
    debouncedLogger = debouncedLogger || debounce(logger, 1000);
    
    const onClick = () => {
        setCounter(counter + 1);
        debouncedLogger();
    }
        
    return (
        <button onClick={ onClick }>{ counter }</button>
    );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Well the event is now really debounced correctly. However, you can see that after you're done mashing the button, `logger()` still outputs 0, it is in fact stuck at 0. This is because the captured listener now represents a stale closure, this closure only has access to the initial value of the counter, bummer!

Some colleagues suggested using `useMemo()` or `useCallback()` but I don't see how these could possibly solve them problem, they simply cache a value or a function, but as soon as a dependency changes (in this case, every time, because our dependency is `counter`) a new function is returned. This gets us back to the first problem.

**Current Solution**

The only reasonable thing I could think of is: if the listener's closure becomes stale, why not offer a method that updates it from within the closure of the debounced function?

```js
const specialDebounce = (listenerFn, delay) => {
    let timeout = null;
    
    // allow dynamic updating of the listener
    let dynamicListenerFn = listenerFn;
    const setListenerFn = (fn) => { dynamicListenerFn = fn; }
    
    const debouncedFn = (...eventArguments) => {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(() => { dynamicListenerFn(...eventArguments); }, delay);
    }

    // return both the debounced function and the listener setter
    return [debouncedFn, setListenerFn];
}
const [debouncedLogger, setLogger] = specialDebounce(() => {}, 1000);
const App = () => {
    const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(0);
    
    const logger = () => { console.log(counter); }
    setLogger(logger);
    
    const onClick = () => {
        setCounter(counter + 1);
        debouncedLogger();
    }
        
    return (
        <button onClick={ onClick }>{ counter }</button>
    );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

**Observations and Question**

Well this approach clearly achieves the desired behavior, but it gives me the feeling that I'm doing something wrong, some weird shenanigans.

Is this approach elegant? Is it an anti-pattern of some sort? Is there a better/cleaner way to deal with this? Is there a React mechanic that I did not consider?

I appreciate the time you granted for this long read as well as your insights.

Comment: Did you research on Stack Overflow? [Search results for `[reactjs] debounce`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Breactjs%5D+debounce)